# SFTP with FileZilla through SSH tunnel with different public keys

Tags: sftp, ssh-tunnel, filezilla

I have setup an SSH tunnel to connect to an AWS transfer server through FileZilla

```
ssh -i ~/bastion-server.pem -L 3111:vpce-id.eu-west-3.vpce.amazonaws.com:22 ec2-user@x.x.x.x
```

Which is working fine.

Then in FileZilla I have my connection string

```
Host: 127.0.0.1 Port:3111 Username:sftpuser key:transfer-server.pem
```

The FileZilla log says

```
Status:         Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3111...
Status:         Using username "Username:sftpuser". 
Status:         Authenticating with public key "~/bastion-server.pem" from agent
```

Why is FileZilla using bastion-server.pem and how can I make it use transfer-server.pem

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla is merely using the keys it can find in the `ssh-agent`.

Try looking at what `ssh-add -l` says and you'll see why it uses that key.
I don't use FileZilla but I expect it looks for standard keys in `~/.ssh/id_{ed25519,rsa}` which it cannot find and falls back to the only key available to it.

Either configure the FileZilla entry to specifiy a key or simply use `scp` (or better yet, `rsync` if possible) which support specifying keys on the command line.